# How to extract part of text that comes before first space in string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to extract only a part of text that comes before first space in string e.g. given **John Mathew**, I want to get should be **John**.

I tried `SUBSTRING` and that worked for names like above but not like these **Morris**, **Stephen** but worked for **John Mclane**, **Hassan Shehryar**. why ?

```
Select 
    PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoName 
From 
    PersonalInfo
Where 
    PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID = @PersonalInfoID
```

The main column is `PersonInfoName`

Comment: Lovely that you tried `SUBSTRING`. If you don't _show us_ what you tried and how the results disappointed it makes it rather difficult to assist you. The code you provided doesn't provide any clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest method is:

```
select (case when PersonalInfoName like '% %'
             then left(PersonalInfoName, charindex(' ', PersonalInfoName) - 1))
             else PersonalInfoName
        end)
```

There is probably no need to write your own function to do this.